# Subsonic race condition detected each new DB connection

Tags: c#, subsonic3

I'm having a hard time debugging a service.

I will start by explaining the cenario that I'm running.
I got 9 databases using their services importations, generations of reports and exporting data.
They all run fine for a day or two but after that subsonic starts to give exceptions when there is a new connection to database, all exceptions are simillar, just change the database operation, there is an exemple:

```
Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.
   at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, Int32 dstOffsetBytes, Int32 byteCount)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
   at SubSonic.DataProviders.DbDataProvider.ExecuteReader(QueryCommand qry) in C:\[path]\SubSonic.Core\DataProviders\DbDataProvider.cs:line 112
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute[T](QueryCommand`1 query, Object[] paramValues) in C:\[path]\SubSonic.Core\Linq\Structure\DbQueryProvider.cs:line 280
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in C:\[path]\SubSonic.Core\Linq\Structure\DbQueryProvider.cs:line 131
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in C:\[path]\SubSonic.Core\Linq\Structure\QueryProvider.cs:line 50
   at SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1.GetEnumerator() in C:\[path]\SubSonic.Core\Linq\Structure\Query.cs:line 85
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at [namespace].ReportManager.GetAllPending() in [path]\ReportManager.cs:line 193
   at [namespace].ReportsServiceHandler.Run() in C:\[path]\ReportsServiceHandler.cs:line 137
```

The only solution so far that I have is to reset the service but I wasn't able yet to discovery what may cause this. I tried to debug it in my local environment but I wasn't able to do it.

Anyone know if there is a bug in subsonic or how can I find the problem in the services?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subsonics3 returns you reader , and you can dispose it following way

```
Query qry = Product.CreateQuery().WHERE("ListPrice > 50.00")
            .AND("Class = L").AND("Color = Yellow");
using(IDataReader rdr = qry.ExecuteReader())
{
 while (rdr.Read()) {
   Console.WriteLine(rdr[Product.Columns.Name].ToString());
 }
}
```

using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ... do your stuff ...
        }

---

i think you need to dispose you connection properly by making use of `using`, because there might be cause connection you used previously still open i.e. not closed.

```
using(var connection = new Connection())
{
}
```

above code dispose you connection. or if it is not there i suggest make use of [Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) and dispose conneciton object after use of it.

Comment: the problem is that the connections are made by subsonic, for exemple:  return Repository.Single<CompanyServiceModuleEntity>(x => x.CompanyID == org && x.ServiceID == service);

Comment: @JoãoSilva - then i think you can take control of creation object and dispose it because i am not sure in current library how you can dispose connection ...

Comment: @JoãoSilva - you can do like this   using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ... do your stuff ...
        }

Comment: @JoãoSilva - updated answer please check ...and let me know which database you are using

Comment: so, you mean I should use call the subsonic only inside an using so it can dispose the connections?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - it best practice that you dispose connection after using it ..that way you will not end up with too many connection with database ...because if you open too many connection to database , it will database performance badly ...and if there are too many connection your database might refuse to take more connection

Comment: I know but subsonic is the one that manage the db connections... I saw that there are some unfixed bugs: https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/176

Comment: @JoãoSilva - ok so suggest you to make used of good library ...if you like upvote/accept answer